# Node or java cassandra api

Tags: java, node.js, cassandra

Hi guys i'm looking at moving my cassandra api layer to nodejs or java, I played a bit with it but i'm still not sure what's better for scalability and maintainance, java client for cassandra seems quite pleasant to work with, anyone has experience with either technology?

Thank you

Comment: Datastax cassandra driver gives you more flexibililty if you are using a J2EE or Java application.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Spring data cassandra, hector and Astyanax as some of the options available for Java apps wanting to integrate with Cassandra.

Comment: If using Java, the datastax java client should be checked out. Astyanax still uses thrift last time I checked (the legacy api), although Hector added CQL3 support just recently.

Comment: Astyanax has a parallel branch that is going to support CQL, check out the [link](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cql-and-cql3)